# OpenCV-3.0.0-beta failure to build on 32-bits and 64-bits Ubuntu12.04 - IPP symbols undefined

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, intel-ipp

Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `ippiTranspose_16u_C4IR'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to`ippiMean_StdDev_16u_C1R'
../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `ippiFilterSobelHorizBorder_8u16s_C1R'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to`ippiNorm_L2_32f_C4R'
../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `ippiMulC_16s_C1IRSfs'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to`ippiNormDiff_L1_8u_C4R'
../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `ippiResizeLinear_16u_C3R'
../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to`ippiNormDiff_Inf_32f_C1MR'
../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `ippiCopySubpixIntersect_8u_C1R'
../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to`ippiErodeBorder_8u_C1R'
../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `ippiCrossCorrNormGetBufferSize'

Comment: Did you use CMake to build OpenCV?  You probably have it set so that IPP or the Intel Performance Primitives are included when compiling.  You're getting that error because you actually don't have those on your system.  Try disabling them by setting the `WITH_IPP` flag to `OFF`, then try rebuilding and compiling again.  However, if you want to compile with IPP, check out this website: http://choorucode.com/2013/10/04/how-to-compile-opencv-with-ipp-support/

Comment: Thanks rayryeng. Yes I wanted to compile with IPP and I used CMake to build OpenCv and had WITH_IPP=ON in the CMake command line. IPP was pre-installed on my computer and IPPROOT was properly set. Furthermore opencv has a static lib 3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/ia32/libippicv.a that may be all that's needed. So I guess what's missing may be just a flag that specifies the library to link with; but where to set such a flag?

Comment: The URL for compiling with IPP is: http://codeyarns.com/2013/10/04/how-to-compile-opencv-with-ipp-support

Answer (score 0):

You can add that libippicv.a library as simple object file to linker command line at the end. Or, treat it as a library "cc ..... -L 3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/ia32 -lippicv" so as ordinary libraries are used while linking.

Comment: I have turned the cmake command into verbose mode, and found out, that the link command line includes 3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx/lib/ia32/libippicv.a and I still get the "undefined symbols"; so they are probably defined in an IPP library that needs to be installed separate from OpenCV. Would anybody point me to the right lib to include. Thanks

Comment: Do you build opencv library itself? With cmake? I wonder how could you get external references to pure IPP function names, whereas ippicv has only renamed functions, like "ippicviFilterSobelHorizBorder_8u16s_C1R".